# can download file in localhost but not server

Tags: php, sql

Anyone face this problem before?
like i implement a backup php script.
when i click the button download.
the file will auto download and store in my localhost folder.

but when i upload the script to server and try to run, the script can run and display the successful message. but no any file download.

```
 //SAVE THE BACKUP AS SQL FILE
  $handle = fopen($DbName.'-Database-Backup-'.$table.date('Y-m-d @h-i-s').'.sql','w+');
  fwrite($handle,$data);
  fclose($handle);
```

below is the script that i wrote. 
[Php script](http://3v4l.org/Ugk95)

Comment: are you sure you have write permissions on that server?

Comment: i already grant all necessary privilege, yes.

Comment: in localhost when i click the button, it's auto generate inside my localhost folder without inform me to save at specific directory path

Comment: Can you edit the server configuration? Or at least visualize it?

Comment: edit? in phpmyadmin ? or?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following header in php.

Example:

header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=my.sql');

header('Content-type: text/plain');

Comment: can download. but inside the content not i wanted. it's just print my function